# How to solve this error in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

> I have try to create database in android, i got this error, i can't
>   understand why this error occur,then i have check code but i can't
>   fix, anybody can tell me why this error occur and how to solve this
>   error.

`07-30 12:03:52.144: E/SQLiteLog(5761): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
 07-30 12:03:52.174: E/SQLiteLog(5761): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/data/data/com.implysoftwares.HotApps/databases/HotApps) - 
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.implysoftwares.HotApps/databases/HotApps'.
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
 07-30 12:03:52.315: E/SQLiteDatabase(5761):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)`

SQLiteDatabase:

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/packagename/databases/";
private static String DB_Name = "HotApps";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

public SQLitedatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_Name, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_Name;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_Name);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_Name;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_Name;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}
```

Comment: Post your code. Do you have a DB named HotApps?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `openDatabase` must be the full path of the database file, and this must be a directory that you are allowed to access.
Either ensure that the path and filename are correct, or use [ContextWrapper.getDatabasePath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) to get a path for your app.

A better idea would be to use [openOrCreateDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29) or [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), which do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should check if DB is created or not.

if you have rooted device, connect to PC and run application. Otherwise, start emulator.

Then open terminal and type

> adb shell // connect to device and open file system us // get root cd
>   data/data/you.package.name/database